# How to display "" itself as a string

Tags: c++

Is there any way "" (double quotes itself) can be displayed as a string in c++

I tried `cout << " "" ";` which obviously does not work.

Comment: Maybe try "\"\"".

Answer (score 8):

You need to escape them with '\' inside your string:

```
cout << " \"\" "
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape your string.

```
cout << " \"\" ";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your string, for example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
    cout << " \"\" ";
}
```

Output:

```
""
```

Answer (score 0):

The two easiest ways I know of are as an escaped value in a string:

```
cout << "\"";
```

and as a character:

```
cout << '"';
```

I generally prefer the latter, as emacs's C++ mode colorizes it better. If you use the former, it gets confused and thinks everything after the third quote is inside a string. It is (debatably) less confusing for humans too.